# Should this answer be deleted/moved to comments?

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

Tor.SE has a [question about guard nodes](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/7048/88). user8289 refers in their [answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7594/88) to an answer I gave before and was marked as accepted answer. However I see this answer only as comment and currently it is downvoted. So I tend to move it to comments. I'm interested in your opinions on this. Should this stay as an accepted answer or should it be moved to comments (or treated in another way)?

Comment: I've given two answers. Maybe a couple of users can vote on which is preferable? If not, I'd probably go with you on the edit/delete option.

Comment: Whenever I refer to someone else's answer I always pt it in an answer (or perhaps in a  question) then provide an excerpt of what was said to explain the reason for the reference.  That is really tough to do in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the first line of that is an answer. Deleting the state file will do what the user wants (though the safety is obviously questionable). I can see that it does have some upvotes - it just has more downvotes, probably because the rambling after it detracts from the actual answer.

I'd say it's worth just editing to leave in the first line and stripping out the rest. The speed & location of the particular node is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, you could just add a single line to the end of your existing answer to say something like "Delete the state file from [...]\TorBrowser\Data\Tor 
and restart Tor if you really need a fresh guard node." Then your answer is complete and the stray answer/comment can be fairly removed.

Comment: Fair point.  Finding references to your answer may make you think of more information that can be included there.  You never know what someone might search for in Google.  It might lead more people to the useful information you post.